# PHP pcntl_signal callbacks are not called

Tags: php, signals, posix, pcntl

This is the complete reproducible code.

```
<?php
class console{
    public static function log($msg, $arr=array()){
        $str = vsprintf($msg, $arr);
        fprintf(STDERR, "$str\n");
    }
}
function cleanup(){
    echo "cleaning up\n";
}
function signal_handler($signo){
    console::log("Caught a signal %d", array($signo));
    switch ($signo) {
        case SIGTERM:
            // handle shutdown tasks
             cleanup();
            break;
        case SIGHUP:
            // handle restart tasks
            cleanup();
            break;
        default:
            fprintf(STDERR, "Unknown signal ". $signo);
    }
}

if(version_compare(PHP_VERSION, "5.3.0", '<')){
    // tick use required as of PHP 4.3.0
    declare(ticks = 1);
}

pcntl_signal(SIGTERM, "signal_handler");
pcntl_signal(SIGHUP, "signal_handler");

if(version_compare(PHP_VERSION, "5.3.0", '>=')){
    pcntl_signal_dispatch();
    console::log("Signal dispatched");
}

echo "Running an infinite loop\n";
while(true){
    sleep(1);
    echo date(DATE_ATOM). "\n";
}
```

When I run this I see the date values each second. Now if I press Ctrl+C `cleanup` function is not called. In fact `signal_handler` is not called.

Here is the sample output.

```
$ php testsignal.php 
Signal dispatched
Running an infinite loop
2012-10-04T13:54:22+06:00
2012-10-04T13:54:23+06:00
2012-10-04T13:54:24+06:00
2012-10-04T13:54:25+06:00
2012-10-04T13:54:26+06:00
2012-10-04T13:54:27+06:00
^C
```

Comment: Wrong. There is your comment. ;)

Comment: There is a discrepancy between the PHP version number in `version_compare()` and the comment after it - would you fix?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `CTRL+C` fires `SIGINT`, which you have not installed handler for:

```
<?php
...
function signal_handler($signo){
...
    case SIGINT:
        // handle restart tasks
        cleanup();
        break;
...
}
...
pcntl_signal(SIGINT, "signal_handler");
...
```

Now it works:

```
$ php testsignal.php
Signal dispatched
Running an infinite loop
2012-10-08T09:57:51+02:00
2012-10-08T09:57:52+02:00
^CCaught a signal 2
cleaning up
2012-10-08T09:57:52+02:00
2012-10-08T09:57:53+02:00
^\Quit
```

Answer (score 4):

It's important to understand how `declare` works: http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.declare.php

it either needs to wrap what ever it's affecting to be declared in the 'root' script (index.php or something similar).

fun fact; the IF check around `declare(ticks = 1);` doesn't matter, if you remove those 3 lines the script will stop working, if you change the check to `if (false)` it will work, the declare seems to be evaluated outside of the normal code flow xD

Comment: This is correct, I was about to post the same correction.

Answer (score 0):

Following Ruben de Vries correction to the compile-time use of declare ticks, there are two things wrong with the original code (other than missing the INT signal).

As Ruben says:

```
if(false) declare(ticks=1);
```

This DOES declare ticks to be handled. Try it!
The docs go on to say how you cannot use variables etc. It's a compile time hack.

Furthermore the use of `pcntl_signal_dispatch()` is *not* a straight replacement for declaring ticks - it must be called during code execution - like ticks do automatically. So calling it once in the head of script like that will only process any signals pending *at that moment*.

To make pcntl_signal_dispatch() operate like using ticks to drive it you'd need to sprinkle it all over your code... depending on precisely where/when you want the interrupts to take effect.

At least:

```
while(true){
    sleep(1);
    echo date(DATE_ATOM). "\n";
    pcntl_signal_dispatch();
}
```

So the original code is actually using ticks for all versions of PHP, and *additionally* checking for just one signal received during the initial boot process if version is greater than 5.3. Not what the OP intended.

Personally I find the use of ticks to drive PCNTL signals a huge messy pain. The "loop" in my case is in third party code, so I cannot add a dispatch method, and it the declare ticks at the top level doesn't work on production unless I add it to every file (some autoload, scoping or PHP7 version specific issue I think).